# please help me understand the parent element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, parent-child

If there is a div className as app already there, why do I need fragment for employee? Wouldn't it be already under the single parent element `<div className = "app>`

```
return (
    <div className="app">
    { showEMployees ? 
    
      <>
      <Employee />
      <Employee />
      <Employee />
      </>
  
      :
      <p> YO YOU CANT ACCESS IT BRO</p>
      
    }
    </div>
  
  );
```

I tried deleting the div classname app but it says it still needs a parent element. And I deleted the fragment and it says the same thing.

Comment: "It says"? What's "it"?

Comment: @AKX [It's it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZG_k5CSYKhg)

Comment: *"why do i need fragment for employee?"* - just remove it to find out. Please also have a look [at the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - you'll receive a badge if you do.

Answer (score 1):

Technically: because there's no syntactical element in the underlying JavaScript that could host three adjacent elements.

```
/* @jsx r */
<div>
  {showEMployees ? (
    <>
      <Employee />
      <Employee />
      <Employee />
    </>
  ) : (
    <p> YO YOU CANT ACCESS IT BRO</p>
  )}
</div>
```

[compiles down to](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBAAgVgzgHmATmEwBQAeAJgSwG4B8aYYA3jABYD2A7gKICyADgDZUCeAppzGAPxgAFMRJgMRUaIx0Atqw7cwwCZLGz5XTkpWTpctpu0iSGZSICUYAFxDjYpgTABNAPLOXAVTABhAIIA5ABUwX29vOgBlCLAASWCAIQAlF1MHCwBfTGBcQgBuNCA)

```
r(
  "div",
  null,
  showEMployees
    ? r(
        React.Fragment,
        null,
        r(Employee, null),
        r(Employee, null),
        r(Employee, null),
      )
    : r("p", null, " YO YOU CANT ACCESS IT BRO"),
);
```

see how a `React.Fragment` element was injected to hold the children? (When rendered into HTML elements by React, the fragment "disappears".)

If you didn't use a fragment, it'd compile down to

```
(r(Employee, null), r(Employee, null), r(Employee, null))
```

which would just be the [comma operator](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator) and you'd end up with only one `Employee` element.

You also shouldn't use an array for a static number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are receiving  is because JSX requires that there be a single parent element wrapping all the elements within a component. So, even if you removed the fragment (<> ... </>), you should still have a single parent element that encloses all the elements inside the component.

In your case, if you want to keep the "app" class as the parent element, you should avoid removing it. However, you can eliminate the fragment and use another element as a container.
For example:

```
return (
  <div className="app">
    {showEmployees ? (
      <div>
        <Employee />
        <Employee />
        <Employee />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <p>YO YOU CAN'T ACCESS IT BRO</p>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

This way, you have a single parent element (the  with the "app" class) that contains the  elements when showEmployees is true and the paragraph when showEmployees is false.

Comment: But that's not what OP wants, OP wants the employee elements to be nested directly within the App div.

Comment: @AKX Word for word the OP simply asks why this is needed, not that they want to remove it.

Comment: thanks peter krebs. i dont understand why it is needed

Answer (score 0):

If you want the employee elements to be directly nested inside the div with the "app" class, you need to keep the "app" div as the direct parent. However, since JSX requires a single parent element for JSX elements, you can use a different approach using an array of elements instead of a fragment.

```
    return (
  <div className="app">
    {showEmployees
      ? [
          <Employee key={1} />,
          <Employee key={2} />,
          <Employee key={3} />,
        ]
      : <p>YO YOU CAN'T ACCESS IT BRO</p>
    }
  </div>
);
```

I hope this can help you